# Python selenium get rid of hyphens and other special html characters

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, soft-hyphen

I scrape websites with selenium and put then the content in pandas to easily use it. My only problem is that when I use the .text function on a selenium webelement, all the special html characters are kept but cannot be deleted because they are invisible. Is there a way to delete them all when scraping ?

Thank you all !

Comment: Can you share example of text and code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered a similar problem awhile ago. Without any reproducible code or HTML it's a bit hard to say, but the best way I found was to **remove special characters was executing a JS script**:

```
driver.execute_script("var element = document.getElementsByClassName('<class_name>');for (var i = element.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {element[i].remove();}")
```

**Replace <class_name> with the name of the class you would like to remove**. Now you can grab the webelement you need without worrying about special characters.